# how to successfully confirming my configuration with git using macos in terminal?

Tags: git, macos, rstudio

Finally started to lean how to use gitHub and Rstudio. After configuring Git with code

`git config --global user.name "birdysui"`
`git config --global user.email birdysui@hotmail.com`

I tried to confirm my configuration with code

`git config --list`

and all I got is this:

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status 
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all -- 
pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

At this point I am not able to type any code anymore. All I can do is to hit the return button. This is what it looks like in the end. I am only able to hit the return button and can't even type exit.

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=birdysui
user.email=birdysui@hotmail.com
(END)
```

This is me using MacOS Mojave, running the latest version of Git. I didn't know if my git worked out or not. I am just a microbiology major try to learn some R programing using Rstudio. When I try to link my Rstudio to GitHub, enable version control, I didn't know if that worked out or not. By the time I tried to start a new project in Rstudio using version control - Git, it tells me Git was not detected on the system path. I just got really confused since I tried my best to follow everything as instructed in my course on coursera.

Comment: Seems that git is ok. Your configuration is saved and the command git is reachable. Try to execute: `which git` and configure the full path in your rstudio settings.

Comment: `(END)` at the end means you're using a pager called [`less`](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/). Learn to configure and use it so that you don't need "*At this point I am not able to type any code anymore. All I can do is to hit the return button. This is what it looks like in the end. I am only able to hit the return button and can't even type exit.*" FAQ: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html. Man manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html

Comment: Press `q` to quit the pager and the arrows to scroll the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I figured out my Git has already installed. But the configuration path in my rstudio setting was wrong. Although there was a git at the path showed in rstudio setting, it's not the one. With code ˚which git˚ in my terminal, i found the correct  path for the git, thus successfully linked my rstudio with github. Thank you for everyone’s help. Also I didn’t know about the q to quit before, thanks.